# Semi-transparent image above content

Tags: transparent, blocking, graphical-logo

Looking for help with the following:

I want a half-transparent logo in the bottom right corner of the page that does *not* block content.

In this case (see image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNkuY.png), the transparent part of the logo png would block the web link below.

Is there any workaround to this?